# Эмуляция плавного движения мышки

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть класс MouseOperations, основан на WinAPI. Все отлично работает, вот только движения мышки не плавные (она просто пропадает в одном месте и появляется уже в заданном). Как сделать прорисовку движения мышки?

Сам класс:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MouseOperations
{
    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags
    {
        LeftDown = 0x00000002,
        LeftUp = 0x00000004,
        MiddleDown = 0x00000020,
        MiddleUp = 0x00000040,
        Move = 0x00000001,
        Absolute = 0x00008000,
        RightDown = 0x00000008,
        RightUp = 0x00000010
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SetCursorPosition(int X, int Y)
    {
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
    }

    public static void SetCursorPosition(MousePoint point)
    {
        SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
    }

    public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
    {
        MousePoint currentMousePoint;
        var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
        if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
        return currentMousePoint;
    }

    public static void MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags value)
    {
        MousePoint position = GetCursorPosition();

        mouse_event
            ((int)value,
             position.X,
             position.Y,
             0,
             0);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MousePoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public MousePoint(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите класс, который последоваьельно через небольшие интервалы времени перемещает курсор на небольшое расстояние.

Comment: Дык оно то и понятно, дело в другом. Хождение по прямым углам только получается. Я не математик, не знаю как реализовать перемещение по диагонали.

Comment: Здесь школьной математики более чем достаточно. Вспомните пропорции.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассуждать:

Представим искомую траекторию как некую функцию во времени. Закон нас не интересует, нам интересна траектория, то есть вектор значений функции.

пусть есть траектория нужного вам движения, допустим `List<Point>`. В чем сейчас проблема? в том, что неизвестны значения функции в промежутках между узлами. Что нужно сделать, чтобы их узнать? Применить один из алгоритмом [интерполяции](http://matlab.exponenta.ru/spline/book1/10.php), например [метод Лагранжа](http://alnam.ru/book_bcm.php?id=11)

Таким образом, вместо траектории со значениями координат с интервалом `dt` получим расширенный вектор траектории с интервалом `dt - k`, следовательно, увеличится точность.

Реализаций методов интерполяции можно найти огромное количество.

Comment: Вы это все для нормальной параметризации кривой
кривой приведите?

Comment: На кибере подсказали использовать Алгоритм Брезенхэма, попробую реализовать на шарпе если позволит время.